# How do you consolidate accounts?

Tags: discussion

How to go about consolidating three stack exchange accounts?

Comment: This question belongs on meta, not the main site.  But you should first check the relevant page in the [help center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: @Caleb why migrate crap questions here?